# PHP Node no longer exists SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a SimpleXMLElement object that I got from parsing a response from oData. I'm looping through the children and it works well as long as it has children (the truth is I'm not even sure if they are its children or if its just a collection). This is how my code looks like:

```
$dataset = soapService->doSoapCall();

$array = $dataset->children()->children();

foreach($rawArray as $element)
{
   $row['Something'] = (string)$element->Something;
   $newArr[] = $row;
}
```

The problem is that this code throws an error of: **PHP Node no longer exists SimpleXML**. I've been trying to check for null or check the count of it but I keep getting the same error. When I look at it from the debugger in net beans it just says its type SimpleXMLElement but I doesn't have any other value or children. Please help.

Note: When I do print_r($array) i get this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

When the object actually has data it returns this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Table] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [EventCode] => 10020 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [EventCode] => 10030 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [EventCode] => 10040 ) ) ) {"code":99200}
```

Comment: [`print_r($array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) ?

Comment: This is what it prints: SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Comment: Now try it on `$dataset`.

Comment: Same thing: SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Comment: I guess its empty, but how can I check if its empty without it blowing up

Comment: When it has data it returns SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Table] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [EventCode] => 10020 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [EventCode] => 10030 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [EventCode] => 10040 ) ) ) {"code":99200}

Comment: which line spits out the "no longer exists"? Inside the loop? or the -children-children call?

Comment: As soon as it gets to the loop.